# Polya's Urn Application, Tossing Paper into a Bin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, polya-urn-model

My question is regarding the problem in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcIDeZ2nLf0&list=PLADLdjl79_mhdmhdxA1Gk8sklGEWJkEKq

You are tossing 300 pieces of crumpled paper into a bin. You miss the first, and make the second. Subsequently, your chance of making each shot is your cumulative win-rate. What is the probability that you will make exactly 298 shots?

Before looking at the solution, here is how I set up this problem. I thought, we need to calculate the probability that exactly one of the remaining 298 shots is a miss: so, we can add the probabilities for the following events: third shot is missed and the rest are hits, fourth shot is missed and the rest are hits, ..., 300th shot is missed and the rest are hits.

Interestingly, I find that each of the above events has equal probability, $\frac{1}{(299)(300)}$ (please correct me if I am wrong). Note, that there are 298 such events (300-3+1). So, I conclude that the answer should be:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{298} \frac{1}{(299)(300)}=\frac{298}{(299)(300)}
$$

However, the answer is $\frac{1}{299}$.

Please help me find where I am going wrong. Also, if you could explain how to solve this problem from a Polya's urn approach (thinking about green balls as hits and red balls as misses, and starting with one of each ball in an urn), that would be great! I have an understanding of Markov chains.

Comment: Without looking at the details, the phrase "you will make $298$ shots" is ambiguous.  It could mean "exactly $298$ shots" or "at least $298$ shots".

Comment: @lulu, this should be "exactly 298 shots."

Comment: The probability of each event is actually $1/(298)(299)$. I guess that you don't need an explanation in view of your mistake, just consider it more carefully (the last denominator in the computing product is obviously 299, the number of previous attempts).

Comment: @JoseL.Arregui
Can you explain why that would be the probability of each event? For example, let us consider the event that the 300th shot is a miss and the rest are hits. This would occur with probability $(1/2)(2/3)(3/4)...(298/299)(1/300)=\frac{1}{(299)(300)}$. Is this not correct?
Thank you!

Comment: In that case, when you are going to make the final shot you have previously made 299 (not 300), and only the first one was a miss, so the probability of the last one being a miss is 1/299. The probability of that event is then $(1/2)(2/3)\cdots(297/298)(1/299)$, the same as in the rest of cases as you know.